# How to apply remote true to html map > area in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemap

In the below example, I have a simplified version of an image map I am using for a Ruby on Rails 4 application. No need to worry about the coordinates because I took most of them out... the image map itself works perfectly.

I want to link each clickable area to an action. Below I am using the url_for helper to do this.

This works, but I would like to have the map area links AJAXing using :remote => true. I can't figure out how to use remote true for a clickable area like this.

I am new to Rails, so I'm sure it is something very simple. I just can't figure out how to do it and it's really bugging me because it will make the application look so much nicer...

```
<%= image_tag "image.png", :width => "263", :height => "340", :border => "0", :usemap => "#map", :class => "map center-block" %>

<map name="map">

<area shape="poly" coords="..." href="<%= url_for post_path('Name') %>" />

<area shape="poly" coords="..." href="<%= url_for post_path('Name') %>" />

</map>
```

Comment: You can't set `remote=true` with the `url_for` helper.  Did you see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268829/remote-true-with-url-for-how-does-one-do-this?answertab=active#tab-top?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Ya, it doesn't work for the url_for helper and I can't wrap an area tag in any other helper either. I read that post a few hours ago. I tried out what it was saying, but the event doesn't seem to fire for a html area tag. It's very well written though.

Comment: You should be able to wrap this in a `link_to`.  Unfortunately, I need to sign off tonight.

Comment: I thought that too, but it doesn't work for the area tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do it directly. You'll have to wing it (i.e. deconstruct what [`link_to`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/606ce3f907cbccd9159bb558c0b57433b42f3975/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L175) is doing and then switch the tag name). Something like

```
<%= content_tag :area,
      shape: 'poly',
      coords: '...',
      href: url_for post_path('Name'),
      'data-remote': 'true'
%>
```

(Did not test, no idea whether the remote mechanism would pick up on a remote `area` as it does on remote `a` and `button`...)

Comment: Hadn't thought of that. Alas, for the area tag, it doesn't seem to work. Good thinking though

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anybody is looking for an answer in future...

As far as I can see, this can't be done in 'the rails way'. However, you can use Javascript instead to set the url. It's a little bit messy, but it works fine.

If anybody figures a rails way in future, I will happily update this and eat my hat!