# Dynamically get Rails DB queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Is there a way to dynamically get a db result in rails? FOr example, I have all of cities indexed with an id. I want to sent the id to the view given a city name, like this Javascript method (I know this doesn't work...)

```
function getCityId (city) {
  return <%= City.where(name => city) %>
end
```

I'm aware there are solutions using ajax, the problem is ajax, as far as I've seen, only works with link_to and form_for, as only these accept the remote: true option. I've though about making an invisible link and initiating a "click()" upon certain conditions, like "keydown" or something, but this is obviously very messy and gross. The other option is to hardcode the ajax, as in the answer cited below, but this is tedious and cluttered.

Is there a way to perform ajax using a simply url_for or comparable helper, or some other way to dynamically get db info? (In know there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268829/remote-true-with-url-for-how-does-one-do-this), but I thought maybe if I asked a more specific question there could be another workaround.)

Answer (score 0):

You look something like that:-

```
# application helper
def getCity(city)
    city = City.find_by_name(city)
end
```

Then, you can directly call from view:-

```
<%= getCity(city_name) %>
```

Comment: That only works intially when the page is loaded. With plain vanilla erb, I can't get new info once the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, in rails, you can use remote: true (within form_for and link_to as you previously stated)

However, don't forget that you can make the raw JQuery.ajax call yourself from your js to to the rails back end to clean up your code.  Look up skip_validation_code and/or grab the validation code and pass it in with the ajax call